# EXC_BAD_ACCESS around Springboard-snapshotting

Tags: ios, ios8

From time to time, Xcode Crashes comes up with a crash that i cannot understand. I pasted the xccrashpoint to [gist](https://gist.github.com/senfi/c9ecdf41d5d6f7b1a8b9)

It states, that Thread 12 crashed somewhere in `CoreGraphics` called by `CorePDF`, called by `QuartzCore` drawing some layers. This seems like OS-called code, maybe via thread 1 which is doing `_saveSnapshotWithName`. So i assume, that this happens when closing the app.

Does anyone have at least a rough idea what is going on here? Maybe someone saw something similar before and can give a hint about what is crashing…

There is nothing special in the app that would cause dramatically wrong behaviour when leaving the app (-> when a screenshot ist taken).

Answer (score 1):

Exec bad errors occur when an attempt is made to access a object or memory location which is not yet initialized.

There might be a problem with an object which you are not defining global.
Check if there is any object you defining and initializing in a method and trying to access out of the scope.

For more details related to errors and crashes, please go through below link.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: Yeah, i see what you are up to. But look at the attached gist: there is no entry point in my app to look at. The call stack of the threads does not really include my app so i guess this is triggered by some OS-code.